# Как сделать проверку на занятость логина?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица users

- id
- login
- name
- password

Как сделать при регистрации проверку на занятость логина?

Есть код:

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
  $name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


  if (mb_strlen($login) < 3 || mb_strlen($login) > 91) {
    echo "Логин должен быть от 3 до 91 символов.";
    exit();
  } else if (mb_strlen($name) < 3 || mb_strlen($name) > 99) {
    echo "Имя должно быть от 3 до 99 символов.";
    exit();
  } else if (mb_strlen($password) < 6 || mb_strlen($password) > 99) {
    echo "Пароль должен быть от 6 до 99 символов.";
    exit();
  }

  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123', 'db');
  $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `name`)
    VALUES('$login', '$password', '$name')");


    $mysqli->close();
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
```

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
$r = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login`=$logincheck";

else if ($login == $logincheck) {
    echo "Логин занят";
    exit();
  }
```

Но ничего не получается. Этот код просто напросто игнорируется.

UPD.

```
  $login = $_POST['login'];
  $name = filter_var(trim($_POST['name']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '123', 'db');
$r = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login`= $logincheck");
// узнаем количество строк, если не 0 - логин уже занят
$result = $r->num_rows;
if($result > 0) {
  echo "Логин занят";
  exit();
}



  if (mb_strlen($login) < 3 || mb_strlen($login) > 21) {
    echo "Логин должен быть от 3 до 21 символов.";
    exit();
  }
  else if (mb_strlen($name) < 3 || mb_strlen($name) > 19) {
    echo "Имя должно быть от 3 до 19 символов.";
    exit();
  } else if (mb_strlen($password) < 6 || mb_strlen($password) > 99) {
    echo "Пароль должен быть от 6 до 99 символов.";
    exit();
  } else if ($login == $logincheck) {
    echo "занято";
    exit();
  }





  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123', 'db');
  $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `name`)
    VALUES('$login', '$password', '$name')");


    $mysqli->close();
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
```

Не понимаю, почему не работает

Comment: Приведите пример кода вместе с тем что вы пробовали, а то не понятно куда вы это вставляете

Comment: А что лежит в `$logincheck`? Где обработка результата запроса который в `$r`?

Comment: А еще строки обычно заключаются в кавычки.

Comment: Дублирует вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003730/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$r = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login`= $logincheck");
// узнаем количество строк, если не 0 - логин уже занят
$result = $r->num_rows;
if($result > 0) {
    echo "Логин занят";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Я так сделал, логин занят не выводиться.

Comment: $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123', 'db');
$r = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login`= $logincheck");
// узнаем количество строк, если не 0 - логин уже занят
$result = $r->num_rows;
if($result > 0) {
    echo "Логин занят";
    exit();
}     так же? Если там же и бд подключать?

Comment: @ItWorld, да, должно работать, в $logincheck лежит логин с формы, то есть $logincheck = $_POST['login'];

Comment: Я дописал в вопрос код, который у меня получился. Он не работает. ХЗ почему

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @ItWorld я же написал, вы в запросе сравниваете столбец login с пустой переменной $logincheck в этой строке: $r = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `login`= $logincheck"); замените здесь $logincheck на $login и должно работать

Comment: Я заменил, тоже самое, ладно, всё равно спасибо вам.

Comment: @ItWorld выложите код формы с которой отправляются данные

Answer (score -2):

```
/*Если нажата кнопка на регистрацию,
     начинаем проверку*/
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
        //Утюжим пришедшие данные
        if(empty($_POST['email']))
            $err[] = 'Поле Email не может быть пустым!';
        else
        {
            if(emailValid($_POST['email']) === false)
               $err[] = 'Не правильно введен E-mail'."\n";
        }

        if(empty($_POST['pass']))
            $err[] = 'Поле Пароль не может быть пустым';

        if(empty($_POST['pass2']))
            $err[] = 'Поле Подтверждения пароля не может быть пустым';

        //Проверяем наличие ошибок и выводим пользователю
        if(count($err) > 0)
            echo showErrorMessage($err);
        else
        {
            /*Продолжаем проверять введеные данные
            Проверяем на совподение пароли*/
            if($_POST['pass'] != $_POST['pass2'])
                $err[] = 'Пароли не совподают';

            //Проверяем наличие ошибок и выводим пользователю
            if(count($err) > 0)
                echo showErrorMessage($err);
            else
            {
                /*Проверяем существует ли у нас 
                такой пользователь в БД*/
                $sql = 'SELECT `login` 
                        FROM `'. BEZ_DBPREFIX .'reg`
                        WHERE `login` = :login';
                //Подготавливаем PDO выражение для SQL запроса
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindValue(':login', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
                $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if(count($rows) > 0)
                    $err[] = 'К сожалению Логин: <b>'. $_POST['email'] .'</b> занят!';

                //Проверяем наличие ошибок и выводим пользователю
                if(count($err) > 0)
                    echo showErrorMessage($err);
                else
                {
                    //Получаем ХЕШ соли
                    $salt = salt();

                    //Солим пароль
                    $pass = md5(md5($_POST['pass']).$salt);

                    /*Если все хорошо, пишем данные в базу*/
                    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'. BEZ_DBPREFIX .'reg`
                            VALUES(
                                    "",
                                    :email,
                                    :pass,
                                    :salt,
                                    "'. md5($salt) .'",
                                    0
                                    )';
                    //Подготавливаем PDO выражение для SQL запроса
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':salt', $salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    header('Location:'. BEZ_HOST .'/');
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: тут есть все, можно подсмотреть и взять то, что нужно

Comment: Maxim Sergeevich-  тут PDO, можно было не скидывать это все, а только по факту дать ответ. Иначе можно скинуть ссылку на https://www.php.net/manual/ пусть там возьмет то, что нужно.